# AWS RDS - Event notifications when backup failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

My company needs to receive notifications to keep track of all the automatic databases backups.

I was checking the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html) and it seems the event subscription in RDS it's what we need to use. Unfortunately I don't see any info related to failed automatic backup/snapshots notification.

Do you know if there are hidden events which should be used for that purpose? Or somehow is it impossible for a backup procedure to fail? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There are no hidden events for failed automatic snapshots.

In my 10 years of working with RDS, I have not seen a single failed automatic snapshots.

Manual snapshots can fail though, when the number of manual snapshots hits the soft limit of 100.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html